# Run a Shell script and read the output in a variable and run another script based on output

Tags: shell-script, read

I am a novice to Linux system. My requirement is to run a Linux status script which echos a message (message is either "App is running" or "App is not running").

If the message is "App is running" then run another shell script to stop the App. Then run the status shell script again after a few seconds. When I read "App is not running", then run Deploy script to deploy new application.

The status script is written in Bash:

```
if [ "$(ps -ef | grep -i cat ${TPSHUB_HOME}/current.pid
        | grep -v grep|awk '{ print $2 }')" ];then 
   echo "TpsHub is RUNNING" 
else 
    echo "TpsHub is NOT running" 
fi 
exit
```

Comment: So what do you have so far? Please post some actual code.

Comment: In addition to @JosephR.'s comment, also can you let us know the platform you are on, please? Just use `uname -a`

Comment: Hi, It is linux machine. We use bash shell. The status script looks like this:
#if [ "$(ps -ef |grep -i TpsHub | grep -v grep|awk '{ print $2 }')" ]
if [ "$(ps -ef | grep -i `cat ${TPSHUB_HOME}/current.pid` | grep -v grep|awk '{ print $2 }')" ]
   then
      echo "TpsHub is RUNNING"
   else
      echo "TpsHub is NOT running"
fi
exit

Comment: I am told it is zLinix machine.

Answer (score 3):

```
  while true ; do
     if .... (your condition)
            echo "TpsHub is RUNNING" 
            . /path/to/stopping/script
            sleep 5
     else
            echo "TpsHub is NOT running" 
            . /path/to/deploy/script
            exit 0
    fi
 done
```

Will keep running in loop until condition is satisfied, then exit upon finishing deploy. If it doesn't stop within 5s, stop script is rerun

Comment: Thank you Very much for your help. I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution that shortens your method of checking whether the PID exists or not by a call to `ps -p` with your PID:

```
while true; do
    if ps -p "$(<$TPSHUB_HOME/current.pid)" &> /dev/null; then
        # announce running, kill tpshub and sleep 
    else
        # announce not running, start tpshub and quit
    fi
done
```

Note that you can also use `xargs` with `ps` and a redirection to use the PID value stored in the file:

```
if xargs ps -p < "$TPSHUB_HOME/current.pid" &> /dev/null; then ...
```

Answer (score 0):

If the process' PID is stored in `$TPSHUB_HOME/current.pid` and you want to figure out whether that PID corresponds to a running process, you may send the 0 "signal" to the PID:

```bsh
if kill -s 0 "$(cat "$TPSHUB_HOME/current.pid")"; then
   echo is running
else
   echo is not running
fi
```

`"$(cat "$TPSHUB_HOME/current.pid")"` could also be written as just `"$(<"$TPSHUB_HOME/current.pid")"` in `bash`.

The special "signal 0" is used for testing for the existence of a particular process but won't actually affect the process at all.

If you want to use `read` to read in the PID from the file (the question was tagged with the [read](/questions/tagged/read) tag):

```bsh
if read pid <"$TPSHUB_HOME/current.pid" && kill -s 0 "$pid"
then
    echo is running
else
    echo 'is not running (or could not read PID file)'
fi
```